# Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Injector has already been destroyed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

In this issue that was recently closed: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44186

A contributer (@jessicajaniuk) [says](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44186#issuecomment-1081243950)

> We believe this is resolved by destroyAfterEach: true. If you're seeing failures that require destroyAfterEach: false, it's likely you have scope leakage in your tests. If you continue to see the original issue, please open a new issue for it.

I was wondering if anyone can elaborate on or suggest strategies on how to identify "scope creep"

I'm also running into this after upgrading to Angular 13 with `destroyAfterEach: true`

Answer (score 17):

The answer of @user11883568 got me in the right direction but using `fakeAsync` didn't help in my case. What I did instead, was to opt-out from teardown on the unit-tests affected by this problem by adding the following as described [here](https://dev.to/this-is-angular/improving-angular-tests-by-enabling-angular-testing-module-teardown-38kh):

For the complete suite, on the existing `TestBed.configureTestingModule`, just add the line:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [...],
        declarations: [...],
        providers: [...],
        teardown: {destroyAfterEach: false}   // <- add this line
    }).compileComponents();
});
```

Or, if the problem occurs only on some of the tests, you can opt-out a describe block with:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    // Deactivate teardown for these tests because of a problem with
    // the primeNg dialog.
    TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
    TestBed.initTestEnvironment(
        BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
        platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
        {teardown: {destroyAfterEach: false}}
    );
});
```

Comment: If your usign **setTimeout()** in function, just add **tick()** greater then **setTimeout** in test.

Comment: @GDBxNS I'm not using `setTimeout()` at all. My problem is caused by a third-party component (a primeNG dialog).

Comment: I tried refactoring my test case but to no avail. After adding `teardown: {destroyAfterEach: false}   // <- add this line` to the specific .spec file - the issue did not popup again. Still seems like a bandaid fix :(

Comment: @JonathanCardoz yes, it's definitely just a workaround and it'd be better to have a real fix for the actual problem (in our case the primeNG dialog), but at least for us, the affected tests are just a few out of 3000+ tests, so this is a LOT better than having to deactivate the teardown completely, which has a huge performance loss.

Answer (score 5):

Using PrimeNG as component library I got this problem in tests for components using any kind of overlay or popup (e.g. dialog, calendar). Simply running these tests in the **fakeAsync** zone fixed it.

I guess it has something to do with pending animations, but my first try - using NoopAnimationsModule in the test setup - did not help.

Comment: Why was this voted down? It is a solution that worked perfectly in my special constellation. Never claimed it to be a general solution, but a hint ("look for external libs doing background tasks like animations").

Comment: In my case using `fakeAsync` didn't help. But I could confirm and narrow down the problem being related to prime-ng dialogs.

Answer (score 5):

For my case this was a symptom of a hidden setTimeout within a service method called by the component under test. The `destroyAfterEach` solution may work but it ignores the root problem which is logic being executed after the test expects to be finished.

So there are 4 solutions:

1. Try using `destroyAfterEach` as the other answers outline
2. Use `fakeAsync` to wrap the test and likely add a `flush` to clear the task queue
3. spyOn the method which contains the asynchronous logic
4. Remove the setTimeout or rewrite the asynchronous logic (with promises or async/await or observables) and write your tests to wait for the logic to finish.

Depending on what you are trying to test only #4 truly executes the code which is causing the error from the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false }` in test.ts file solved the problem for me.

Comment: How is this different from accepted answer? And - this feels like the real problem was just swept under the rug.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when testing a NGRX Observable.

The solution was to wrap the tests inside of `.toSatisfyOnFlush()`:

```
expect(observable$).toSatisfyOnFlush(() => {
    expect(observable$).toBeObservable(hot(''));  // Error occurred when this was outside
    expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```